# Laravel Nova Card Metrics Auto Update Without Refresh Page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, auto-update, laravel-nova

I want to update Laravel Nova Card metrics on specific interval without refreshing page.

**But without modifying Laravel Nova Core files.**

Is there any way which makes it easy **to do on any Laravel Nova Card**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe they are meant to be used that way. You will end up writing your own component to do that.